# A parameter in helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've just watched Railscasts pro episode 250 and I don't understand one thing. I talk about this line:

```
<%= link_to "Log out", session_path("whatever"), method: 'delete' %>
```

Author says something like that:

> session path helper method can expect an id to be passed through here

My controller action:

```
  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Looged out"
  end
```

In my route.rb file:

```
  resources :sessions
```

Why can't I just pass in `<%= link_to "Log out", session_path(), method: 'delete' %>`? When I do it i get an error:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"sessions"} missing
>   required keys: [:id]

Why id is required here?

After all I don't use this parameter anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we define a routes for an controller, we add this following line to routes file

```
resources :sessions
```

This above line, implicitly creates 7 default routes

```
                                     sessions GET      /sessions(.:format)                                                                 sessions#index
                                              POST     /sessions(.:format)                                                                 sessions#create
                                  new_session GET      /sessions/new(.:format)                                                             sessions#new
                                 edit_session GET      /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)                                                        sessions#edit
                                      session GET      /sessions/:id(.:format)                                                             sessions#show
                                              PUT      /sessions/:id(.:format)                                                             sessions#update
                                              DELETE   /sessions/:id(.:format)                                                             sessions#destroy
```

Here, for the `destroy` action the route is `/sessions/:id(.:format)` with `DELETE` method. As the url needs an `:id` in the url, so you need to send some id. id means it should not be only integer, it can be anything like string. So they use 'whatever' in that url while deleting the session.

Answer (score 1):

The route is what is enforcing the missing id. I can't see the rest of your code but you probably have a route somewhere that looks like this:

```
session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)           sessions#show
```

This route requires that you call it, with an id.

Comment: Thanks. I use `resources :sessions` in `route.rb`

Comment: You can either add a new route or just pass anything (eg, 'whatever') into `session_path()` to satisfy the parameter requirement.